# How do I override css with html to float inline pull-quote left?

Tags: html, css, blogs

I am trying to format an article hosted by a third-party blogging website where I do not have access to the css style sheet.

I would like to float a pull-quote to the left, instead of the automatic right as predefined in the pull-quote class. Since I cannot edit the style sheet, I was hoping for an inline style tag in html that I may use to override the css.

Currently I have: `<div class="pullquote">insert pullquote here</div>`

I am extremely new with html and css, so anything is much appreciated.

Comment: You need inline styles. http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/qt/tipcssinlinesty.htm

Comment: This gives information on CSS precedence (inline, embedded, external): http://www.boogiejack.com/CSS_2.html This gives information about specificity: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ Using these links, you can determine how you can change your styles.

Answer (score 3):

For your case you can just use inline css.ie specifying style as an attribute of the div.

For your information the order of invocation of css is as follows

1. Inline CSS
2. Embedded CSS
3. External CSS

More details can be found at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

If that doesnt solve your problem,

You can override any css using `!important`.It means, essentially, what it says; that '**this is important, ignore subsequent rules, and any usual specificity issues, apply this rule!**'

According to the [docs](http://www.yellowjug.com/web-design/the-importance-of-important-in-css/)

> When an !important rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever
>   it is in the declaration list. Although, !important has nothing to do
>   with specificity.  Using !important is bad practice because it makes
>   debugging hard since you break the natural cascading in your
>   stylesheets.

So try this to override the float right

```
<div class="pullquote" style="float:left !important;">insert pullquote here</div>
```

The above example is what is called the inline css which uses `!important` also.

As @j0861 mentioned in his comments `Using !important is bad practice because it makes debugging hard`

Comment: I would avoid ever citing w3schools. Just a word of advice. Second, on one hand you seem to be advocating the use of `!important`, but then go on to note that "Using !important is bad practice because it makes debugging hard".

Comment: oh i see @j08691. I was unaware of that..Thanks for the valuable information.I was just trying to say what i knew..

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
<div class="pullquote" style="float:left">insert pullquote here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply inline-styling to any HTML element.

Where you may have a stylesheet that looks like this:

```
p {
    color: #000;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:underline
}
```

You can directly apply this, and any other combination of styling attributes to an element (for this example a single paragraph line) by using the `style` attribute like this:

```
<p style="color:#000;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline">Some text here</p>
```

In your case you would just need to add:

```
<div class="pullquote" style="float:left;">insert pullquote here</div>
```